# Java Midi produces Registry Error

Tags: java, windows, registry, runtime-error, midi

Is there any way to resolve this common Midi error **without manually changing the registry.**

```
Jan 05, 2015 1:17:05 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows   RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
```

This seems to occur every time I try to `open()` the `MidiSystem.getSequencer()`.

I have yet to see any solution, I have been searching for some time now.

Comment: Automate changing the registry?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Problem is, I'm pretty sure that requires administrator privileges and I am trying to avoid prompting users to enter administrator passwords as this is for a game engine I'm creating.

Comment: The problem you are running into is an operating system issue (and at a lower level then the Java Virtual Machine). The usual solution is to automate the registry setting process with a shell script or installer; for example [NSIS: Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/) is open-source and can be used to build a graphical installer and set your registry keys. The fact that the installer may require Adminstrator rights is immaterial to the rights that your software will run as (AFAIK) I try to avoid running Windows.